# Trouble getting view to line up correctly

Tags: java, android

When I press my add button a view is shown and should be directly below the add button. However when I click the button there is some space between the add button and the view added. I have tried setting the gravity to top in the xml and java file. When I press the add button again and get the next view the first view it pushed up to where it is supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int count = 1;
int layoutUse[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addTroopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTroop);

    addTroopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count <= 2)
            {
            //inputName(v);
                inputName(v);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    });

    Button removeTroop1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove1);
    removeTroop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            removeTroop1();
        }
    });
    Button removeTroop2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.remove2);
    removeTroop2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            removeTroop2();
        }
    });

}

public void inputName(final View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //alert.setTitle("Enter Name and Rank");
    alert.setMessage("Please Enter A Name");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      Editable name = input.getText();
      addTroop(name);
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
}

public void addTroop(Editable name){

        if(layoutUse[0] == 0 && count == 1)
        {
            LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.manageTroopsMain);
            LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.trpLayout1);
            Button troop1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.troop1);
            troop1.setText("Button 1");
            mainView.removeView(layout1);
            mainView.addView(layout1);
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutUse[0]++;
            count++;
        }
        else if(layoutUse[1] == 0 && count == 2)
        {
            LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.manageTroopsMain);
            LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.trpLayout2);
            Button troop2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.troop2);
            troop2.setText("Button 2");
            mainView.removeView(layout2);
            mainView.addView(layout2);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutUse[1]++;
            count++;
        }

}

public void removeTroop1(){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.trpLayout1);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layoutUse[0]--;
    count--;
}

public void removeTroop2(){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.trpLayout2);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    layoutUse[1]--;
    count--;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In my xml file I had set the initial visibility of my views to invisible. Setting them to gone fixed this. I guess the views were getting in the way just being invisible so by setting them to gone they were really gone.